# Find XML Tag after known tag on one tree level

Tags: c#, xml, tags, nodes

My problem is, that I don´t know how to find a xml tag which is on one tree level with another. To make this more clear:

I have an xhtml form and need to parse label (Questions) and the answer this looks like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <form>
    <div id="field1-container">
     <label for="field1"> 1. Question </label>
     <input id="field1" other attributes /> 
    </div>
    <div id="field2-container">
     <label for="field2">
     <textarea id="field2"> </textarea>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I´m able to find the questions with sth. like:

```
Xdocument xmlForm = xDocument.Load(myXmlForm.xml);

var quest = from query in xmlForm.Descendants("label")

 select new
 {
  questionFromXML = form.Value,
 };
```

How can I now find the tag of my answer field. I don´t know how to do this with descendants, because I have several divs on several tree levels.

I hope anybody can help me :-)

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Is there no one with an idea? :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself:

There is something like form.NextNode which findes the next Node - took a while until i found out.